# c++, opecv: HoughLines() doesn't receive the values passed by trackbars

Tags: c++, opencv, line, detection, houghlines

I'm supposed to detect the two white lines of the road with the function HoughLines. I use three trackbars in order to find the best parameters to detect ONLY the two white lines of the road. I have tried this: (the problem is that it looks like even if I change the values of the trackbars it doesn't updates the images, it is still at the first values). I'm using opencv with c++.

Without trackbars it works, but it's almost impossibile finding good values without it because I don't know how to tune the parameters and the image is pretty complex.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <opencv2/core.hpp>
#include <opencv2/highgui.hpp>
#include <opencv2/imgproc.hpp>
#include <opencv2/calib3d.hpp>


using namespace cv;
using namespace std;

const int kernel_size = 3;

Mat src, src_gray;
Mat dst, detected_edges;
Mat cdst;

int slider_value_one;
int slider_value_two;
int slider_value_three;


vector<Vec2f> lines; // will hold the results of the detection

static void Hough_transform(int, void*)
{
    // Standard Hough Line Transform
    HoughLines(detected_edges, lines, 1, CV_PI/180, 130,slider_value_one,slider_value_two); // runs the actual detectio
    // Draw the lines
    for( size_t i = 0; i < lines.size(); i++ )
    {
        float rho = lines[i][0], theta = lines[i][1];
        Point pt1, pt2;
        double a = cos(theta), b = sin(theta);
        double x0 = a*rho, y0 = b*rho;
        pt1.x = cvRound(x0 + 1000*(-b));
        pt1.y = cvRound(y0 + 1000*(a));
        pt2.x = cvRound(x0 - 1000*(-b));
        pt2.y = cvRound(y0 - 1000*(a));
        line( cdst, pt1, pt2, Scalar(0,0,255), 3, CV_AA);
    }
    //printing
    imshow("standard Hough Line Transform", cdst);
}//HoughTransform



int main(int argc, const char * argv[]) {
    //-----Loads an image
    src = imread("/Users/massimilianolorenzin/Documents/Progetti\ XCode/lab4/lab4/lab4/images/road2.png");
    /// ---- CANNY DETECTOR
    /// Convert the image to grayscale
    cvtColor( src, src_gray, CV_BGR2GRAY);
    /// Reduce noise with a kernel 3x3
    blur( src_gray, detected_edges, Size(3,3) );
    /// Canny detector
    Canny( detected_edges, detected_edges, 150, 450, kernel_size );

    // Copy edges to the images that will display the results in BGR
    cvtColor(detected_edges, cdst, COLOR_GRAY2BGR);



    /// ---- HOUGH LINE TRANSFORM
    namedWindow("standard Hough Line Transform"); // Create Window

    //first TrackBar
    createTrackbar( "First Par", "standard Hough Line Transform", &slider_value_one, 200, Hough_transform);
    Hough_transform(slider_value_one,0 );

    //second TrackBar
    createTrackbar( "Second Par", "standard Hough Line Transform", &slider_value_two, 100, Hough_transform);
    Hough_transform(slider_value_two, 0 );

    //third TrackBar
    createTrackbar( "Third Par", "standard Hough Line Transform", &slider_value_three, 100, Hough_transform);
    Hough_transform( slider_value_three, 0 );
//printing
    imshow("Input Image",src);
    imshow( "edges", detected_edges );

    waitKey(0);
    return 0;
```

HoughLines() looks doesn't answer at the values set with the trackbars. The window appear normally, slider_value_one, slider_value_two, slider_value_three have the right values because I printed and i saw them, so I don't understand why HoughLines() doesn't take the passed values.

Comment: try adding waitKey(1) in a loop instead of the single waitKey(0). Atm your waitKey is only performed once, so the imshow in your function will not show anything after an asynchronous call.

Comment: Please add a sample image of your expected output to the question.

Answer (score 0):

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/7C5qg.png)

Above there is the input image, while below there is the final ouput. I am asked, in this step, just to create the two lines to the side of the road, coloring the area between the two lines( like in the photo) is requested in the next step.

Comment: Hi Micka. Thank you for answering. I have added waitKey(1) as you suggested, i put it inside the function Hough_transform at the end of it, but it looks that it doesn't change anything. Actually, (after removing the final waitkey(0), When I run the code, it loads the image, the first trackbar, then the second one and finally the third one in three different ( and short) moments. But then, it closes immediately the window and I can't change anything.